# How to check "readerDidFinish" method in delegate class without busy waiting?

Tags: ios, objective-c

First off, I admit that I am a bit of a noob when it comes to Objective-C and Xcode, but I have read quite of bit of Apple's introductory documentation and tutorials. That being said, I'm not really sure how to handle this seemingly basic API query issue.

I'm developing an iPhone app where I use an external library to call an API. The results are handled by a custom delegate class, which is required to implement these methods:

```
readerDidStart
readerDidFinish
```

I can store the results of the API call in my custom delegate class with no problem. The issue is that I need to wait until the `readerDidFinish` delegate method is called before I access them.

My question: what is the best way to handle this situation efficiently? I'm guessing I would update my UI inside the `readerDidFinish` method implementation, but I'm not sure if there's something in the Apple libraries that handles this instead

Comment: Here is how this all works: All over your application, you write code that will be called by iOS at the right time. User taps on a button, your code gets called. User swipes the screen, your code gets called. User enters text, your code gets called. These methods are just the same: If that reader finishes, then your method readerDidFinish gets called. You don't wait for it, just like you don't wait for the user to tap on a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two delegates methods are 1 type of "call-back functions" that the third party library calls to let your app know about those events.  Just implement the two methods.

There is no efficient solution, you app should just wait until both events are called.

If you don't want your uses to touch anything UI items you can use a progress view to draw the spiny circle thing. I like SVProgressView.

Comment: I just went ahead and displayed the spinny circle, then rendered the results of the call when readerDidFinish is triggered. I think I was just thinking about this problem incorrectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is the view controller also the delegate? In that case, you can make your UI updates in the readerDidFinish method. Remember to always make changes to the UI in the main thread.

If the delegate is a separate class (not the view controller), than you might want to implement an observer pattern using NSNotification.

You can subclass NSNotification and trigger it when the readerDidFinish method is called.

The view controller should add itself as an observer in viewWillAppear and remove itself in viewWillDisappear.

Here's a very nice introduction to notifications by Mattt Thompson: http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/

Or post some code if you need more help.